# Python dictionaries not copied properly causing repetitions, how to get this right?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, list-comparison

I'm writing a function which is supposed to compare lists (significant genes for a test) and list out common elements (genes) for all possible combinations of the selection of lists.

These results are to be used for a venn diagram thingy...

The number of tests and genes being flexible.

The input JSON file looks something like this:

```
| test              | genes                                                 |
|-----------------  |---------------------------------------------------    |
| p-7trt_1/0con_1   | [ENSMUSG00000000031, ENSMUSG00000000049, ENSMU...     |
| p-7trt_2/0con_1   | [ENSMUSG00000000031, ENSMUSG00000000037, ENSMU...     |
| p-7trt_1/0con_2   | [ENSMUSG00000000037, ENSMUSG00000000049, ENSMU...     |
| p-7trt_2/0con_2   | [ENSMUSG00000000028, ENSMUSG00000000031, ENSMU...     |
| p-7trt_1/0con_3   | [ENSMUSG00000000088, ENSMUSG00000000094, ENSMU...     |
| p-7trt_2/0con_3   | [ENSMUSG00000000028, ENSMUSG00000000031, ENSMU...     |
```

So The function is follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
def get_venn_compiled_data(dir_loc):
    """return json of compiled data for the venn thing
    """
    data_frame = pd.read_json(dir_loc + "/venn.json", orient="records")
    number_of_tests = data_frame.shape[0]
    venn_data = []
    venn_data_point = {"tests": [], "genes": []} # list of genes which are common across listed tests
    binary = lambda x: bin(x)[2:] # to directly get the binary number
    for dec_number in range(1, 2 ** number_of_tests):

        # resetting
        venn_data_point["tests"] = []
        venn_data_point["genes"] = []

        # using a binary number to get all the cases
        for index, state in enumerate(binary(dec_number)):
            if state == "0":
                continue

            # putting in all the genes from the first test
            if venn_data_point["tests"] == []:
                venn_data_point["genes"] = data_frame["data"][index].copy()

            # removing the ones which are not common in current genes state and this.tests
            else:
                for gene_index, gene in enumerate(venn_data_point["genes"]):
                    if gene not in data_frame["data"][index]:
                        venn_data_point["genes"].pop(gene_index)

            # putting the test in the tests list
            venn_data_point["tests"].append(data_frame["name"][index])

        venn_data.append(venn_data_point.copy())
    return venn_data
```

I'm basically abusing the fact that binary number generate all possible combinations of 1's and 0's so corresponding every place of the binary number with a test, and for every binary number, if 0 is present then the list corresponding to that test is not taken for list comparison.

I tried my best to explain, please ask in the comments if I was not clear.

After running the function I am getting an output in which there are random places where test sets are repeated.

[This is the test input file.](https://abhishek-deshmukh.ml/static/venn_question_stackoverflow/venn.json)

and

[This is what cameout as the output](https://abhishek-deshmukh.ml/static/venn_question_stackoverflow/output.json)

Any help is highly appreciated Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, found my mistake will put the solution here in sometime

Answer (score 0):

I realized what error I was making

I assumed that the binary function will magically always generate the string with the number of places I needed, Which it doesn't.

After updating the binary function to add those zeros things are doing fine.

```py
import pandas as pd
def get_venn_compiled_data(dir_loc):
    """return json of compiled data for the venn thing
    """
    # internal variables
    data_frame = pd.read_json(dir_loc + "/venn.json", orient="records")
    number_of_tests = data_frame.shape[0]
    venn_data = []

    # defining internal function
    def binary(dec_no, length=number_of_tests):
        """Just to convert decimal number to binary of specified length
        """
        bin_number = bin(dec_no)[2:]

        if len(bin_number) < length:
            bin_number = "0" * (length - len(bin_number)) + bin_number

        return bin_number

    # list of genes which are common across listed tests
    venn_data_point = {
        "tests": [],
        "genes": [],
    }


    for dec_number in range(1, 2 ** number_of_tests):

        # resetting
        venn_data_point["tests"] = []
        venn_data_point["genes"] = []

        # using a binary number to get all the cases
        for index, state in enumerate(binary(dec_number)):
            if state == "0":
                continue

            # putting in all the genes from the first test
            if venn_data_point["tests"] == []:
                venn_data_point["genes"] = data_frame["data"][index].copy()

            # removing the ones which are not common in current genes state and this.tests
            else:
                for gene_index, gene in enumerate(venn_data_point["genes"]):
                    if gene not in data_frame["data"][index]:
                        venn_data_point["genes"].pop(gene_index)

            # putting the test in the tests list
            venn_data_point["tests"].append(data_frame["name"][index])

        venn_data.append(venn_data_point.copy())
    return venn_data
```

If anyone else has a more optimized algorithm for this, help is appreciated.